# Web Page Resources Not Loading while deploying in AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jar, war

I am running a Spring Boot Server with a React front-end. I've built the React Project to production and copied the contents of the build to the Webapp folder in my spring project. It worked perfectly when I ran it locally but when I'm uploading the WAR to AWS, the web content is showing a Whitelabel error page.

[WhiteLabel Error Page when hosted in AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsqOK.png)

I tried changing the packaging to JAR because the AWS logs said that a JAR was being launched by the Webapp. But even with JAR packaging everything worked fine locally and not in AWS.
 Below is my WebMvc Config file I'm using to direct my '/' requests to the index.html file in src/main/webapp

```
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final long MAX_AGE_SECS = 3600;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE")
                .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot by default allows the web files to be stored in /public or /static or /resources and not in /webapp. And these locations need not be added via config, I just needed to add an empty controller class.

I removed the addResourceHandler function, created an empty controller class

```
@Controller
public class MyClass{}
```

and moved my web files to /resources/public folder. And Spring Boot took care of the configuration. 
Why it worked fine locally and did not work in AWS is still a mystery to me.

Read this quote along with the solution to my problem. Thought it was worth a share.

Quote: "The only way to have fewer bugs in your code is not to write code whenever possible. Use what is already provided, even if that takes some research, the return is worth it."